# Does Ghost Recon Future Soldier have a split-screen coop campaign mode?

Tags: ghost-recon-future-soldier

I've read somewhere that it is indicated that it does, but some posts on the internet seems to indicate the opposite.

Is there an offline, two player campaign mode a-la Splinter Cell Conviction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Straight from [Joystiq](http://www.joystiq.com/2012/05/26/ubisoft-addresses-lack-of-split-screen-co-op-in-ghost-recon-fut/):

"...split-screen multiplayer doesn't exist for the game's campaign mode..."

[IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/ghost-recon-future-soldier/Campaign) confirms this. It sounds like the game was advertised as having it, but was left out of the final product.

**Edit:**

[Guerilla](http://www.ign.com/wikis/ghost-recon-future-soldier/Guerrilla_Mode) mode is split-screen, but is more like terrorist hunt in *Rainbow Six: Vegas 2* or horde in *Gears of War*.